# inspecting an undefined object's keys and values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, debugging, sails.js

I come from a `ruby` background and am basically not familiar with debugging `undefined` objects that still have `keys` and `values` within it.

I'm using `sails 0.11`, `node 0.12` and starting `node` in debug mode `node debug app.js`. I've set a breakpoint with `debugger;` and am using `repl` to debug the code. Below is the code with the `debugger`.

```
waterlock.engine.findOrCreateAuth(criteria, attr, function(err, user) {

      if (err) return res.badRequest(err);
      delete user.password;

      //create Business
      var businessAttrs = { name: params.businessName };
      Business.create(businessAttrs, function(err, business) {

        if (err) return res.badRequest(err);

        //create BusinessAccount and associate with user and Business
        var businessAccountAttrs = {
          userId: user.id,
          businessId: business.id,
          active: true
        };

        BusinessAccount.create(businessAccountAttrs, function(err, businessAccount) {
          debugger;
          if (err) return res.badRequest(err);

          debugger;
          return res.ok({user: user, 
                          businessAccount: businessAccount, 
                          business: business});
        });
```

now in the debug console whenever I type `user`, I get `undefined`. But if I type `user.id` I get a proper number.

**First question:** When I type `user`, why doesn't it return a full object back with all the keys and values like `{id: 1, name: "Jimbo"}` instead of `undefined`.

**Next question** is how can I inspect the `undefined` object to output the object's keys and values in a clear manner like `{id: 1, name: "Jimbo"}`?

I've tried `user.inspect()` and `JSON.stringify(user)` but `inspect` gives me `'{ id: 17,\n  auth: \n   { id: 17,\n     user: 17,\n     email: \'mail@gmail.... (length: 585)'` and `stringify` gives me `'{"id":17,"auth":{"id":17,"user":17,"email":"mail@gmail.com","numFailedL... (length: 514)'` which is better but it still doesn't show everything and it's not very clean.

**Third question:** As in the code above I would like to send `JSON` back like `res.ok({user: user, business: business, businessAccount: businessAccount});` but I don't think it will work because they're all `undefined`! What is the best way to send all objects back through `JSON`?

Currently after trying to call `res.ok` it returns `TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object` in the console.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this and it's very strange. `undefined` is not an object and cannot have properties, so if `user` is `undefined`, `user.id` would throw an error (undefined is much like a null reference). I can only imagine that there is a strange issue you encountered with the debugger tool you're using. In the mean time, try `JSON.stringify(user, undefined, 4);` to format the `user` object nicely when logging it out to the console.